# Will all mass eventually pool together?

Tags: gravity, spacetime

WARNING: no formal physics training

I've been trying to understand the idea of space-time and gravity. Intuitively, it seems like you can think of space-time as a sheet of fabric. Mass sits on the fabric and the bigger the mass, the bigger the depression in the fabric. The bigger the depression, the steeper the slope down towards the center of the mass and thus the stronger the gravitational pull. If this is a correct assumption, then will all mass eventually pool into one global space-time minimum?

If this is all wrong, please correct me. I've never taken a single physics course, but am starting to read about it and can't stop thinking about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the eventual fate of the universe is known for certain.  I believe the "big crunch" is considered a possibility but at this point a pretty unlikely one. However, that would not be all the mass concentrated in the middle of the big empty universe--it would be the entire universe collapsing.

On smaller time and space scales (like the Milky Way for the next $10^{10}$ years) the reason things do not crash together is because of angular momentum--the same reason the Earth doesn't fall into the Sun.  Gravity pulls on it, but momentum carries it in a perpendicular direction, leading to an orbit instead of a crash. If you want to think of it as a dimple in the sheet of spacetime, that's fine--the Earth slides endlessly around the dimple. But there is no friction so it never slows down and moves closer to the middle of the dimple.

Comment: I didn't realize there was no friction to degrade the momentum of orbiting bodies. Cool. Also weird. How could there be no friction? I'll have to look into this. Thanks!

Comment: There is no substance in space to rub against. No rubbing means no fiction.